# How to calculate a maximum-bottleneck path with igraph?

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

Given a capacity network with a single source and a single sink, how can I calculate the [maximum-bottleneck path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem) (also known as the widest path or maximum capacity path problem) using igraph?

I've read (e.g. [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f08/lectures/lect1007.pdf) or even with pseudocode [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552964/finding-path-with-maximum-minimum-capacity-in-graph)) that it is possible with some modifications to Dijkstra’s algorithm, but I do not want to dive into algortihm development but use igraph instead.

Example

```r
library(igraph)
set.seed(21)

nodes = cbind(
'id' = c('Fermenters', 'Methanogens', 'carbs', 'CO2', 'H2', 'other', 'CH4', 'H2O')
)

from <- c('carbs', rep('Fermenters', 3), rep('Methanogens', 2), 'CO2', 'H2')
to <- c('Fermenters', 'other', 'CO2', 'H2', 'CH4', 'H2O', rep('Methanogens', 2))
weight <- sample(1 : 20, 8)

links <- data.frame(from, to, weight, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


net = graph_from_data_frame(links, vertices = nodes, directed = T)

## Calculate max-bottleneck here !


# # disabled because just vis
# plot(net, edge.width = E(net)$weight)

# require(networkD3)
# require(tidyverse)
# 
# d3net <- igraph_to_networkD3(net, group = rep(1, 8))
# forceNetwork(
#     Links = mutate(d3net$links, weight = E(net)$weight), Nodes = d3net$nodes,
#     Source = 'source', Target = 'target',
#     NodeID = 'name', Group = "group", Value = "weight", 
#     arrows = TRUE, opacity = 1, opacityNoHover = 1
# )
```

[image]

So with respect to the example, how would I calculate the maximum capacity path from `carbs` to `H2O`?

Comment: Max-Flow solves a related but imho different problem, which is to calculate the largest possible flow between 2 vertices. The problem which I'm interested in is about _finding a path between two designated vertices in a weighted graph, maximizing the weight of the minimum-weight edge in the path._ (copied from wikipedia).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how efficient this would be, but you could use igraph to find all "simple" paths, then calculate the minimum edge weight of each, then choose the max...

```
require(tibble)
require(igraph)

nodes = data_frame('id' = c('A', "B", "C", "D"))

links = tribble(
  ~from, ~to, ~weight,
  "A" , "B", 10,
  "B", "C", 10,
  "C", "D", 6,
  "A", "D", 4,
)

net = graph_from_data_frame(links, vertices = nodes, directed = T)

simple_paths <- all_simple_paths(net, "A", "D")

simple_paths[which.max(
    sapply(simple_paths, function(path) {
      min(E(net, path = path)$weight)
    })
)]

# [[1]]
# + 4/4 vertices, named, from 061ab8d:
# [1] A B C D
```

Comment: That indeed would be a solution (to be accepted later if nobody comes up with a more efficient approach). As you correctly pointed out, performance (and also memory requirements) would become an issue for real-world graphs (1k+ nodes)

Comment: On my actual usecase, which is a rather linear graph with just a few loops and ~1k nodes this solution does not compute in finite time. That's why I did not tag it as accepted.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which part of it? `min`, `sapply`, `$`, and `which.max` are all highly optimized base functions and they're only working with a list of numerics at that point, which they should be able to handle easily. `igraph::all_simple_paths` is some magic that I don't understand, so I don't know how performant that should be. How many simple paths exist in your use case? Maybe it's `igraph::E`'s extraction of edges in the `sapply`?

Comment: help file warns: "Note that potentially there are exponentially many paths between two vertices of a graph, and you may run out of memory when using this function, if your graph is lattice-like."

Comment: I totally agree. I've seen the help warning as well. It never comes back from `igraph::all_simple_paths` which enumerates all paths, which will fail for larger directed graphs if the have loops etc. As said before, I also consider the solution just a workaround. The correct solution would be an adopted dijstra (aka shortest path) implementation that takes the nature of the problem into account (see refs in question).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the same idea as in [IGRAPH IN R: Find the path between vertices that maximizes the product of edge attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032499/igraph-in-r-find-the-path-between-vertices-that-maximizes-the-product-of-edge-a). Invert the weights, divide by the total to keep the weights < 1 (to keep the log-weights positive), and take the min:

```
x<-shortest_paths(net,3,8, weights=-log(E(net)$weight/sum(E(net)$weight)), output="epath")[[2]]
E(net)[x[[1]]]
min(E(net)$weight[x[[1]]])
```

which gives

```
+ 4/8 edges from 57589bc (vertex names):
[1] carbs      ->Fermenters  Fermenters ->H2          H2         ->Methanogens Methanogens->H2O
[1] 10
```

Comment: As discussed in a (unfortunately author-deleted answer) the shortest path with just edge rescaling does not compute the maximum bottlneck path. To do so dijkstra needs to be changed to use a different argmax over the minimal width. See http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f08/lectures/lect1007.pdf section 13.3 for details.